# How to implement a function to convert a generic typed array to a generic typed 2-dimensional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
public static <T> T[][] toTwoDim(T[] array)
```

The function signature as it is above..
It's a generic typed function, which can be used no matter what type is the data contained in the array.
generally, it receives an array, and return a 2-dimensional array with its half elements in the first row, and the other half in the second row.
I 've no idea how to implement it cause I could not create a generic typed 2-dimensional array inside the function.
Some one help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: The exact procedure is not very important to care about, I think.The main trouble I introduced is that how could I create the appropriate return value, aka a generic typed 2-dimensional array.We can suppose a simpler mapping, as I described in the original post: the function splits the array into two parts,every part has its half elements, and one part stored in the first 'row' of the 2-dimensional array and the other part in the second 'row'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the perfect solution:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[][] toTwoDim(T[] array) {
    Class<T> ctype = (Class<T>) array.getClass().getComponentType();
    int halfLength = array.length / 2;
    T[][] ret = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(ctype, 2, 1);
    T[] r1 = (T[]) Array.newInstance(ctype, halfLength);
    T[] r2 = (T[]) Array.newInstance(ctype, array.length - halfLength);
    ret[0] = r1;
    ret[1] = r2;
    for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++)
        r1[i] = array[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - halfLength; i++) {
        r2[i] = array[i + halfLength];
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String[] a) {
    Integer[] bar = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Integer[][] dims = toTwoDim(bar);
    for (Integer[] r : dims) {
        for (Integer d : r) {
            System.out.print(d + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output:
1 2
3 4 5

the generic type of the 'toTwoDim' function is erased, but the incoming array's element type could be obtained via reflection!

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this for quite a bit, and my understanding, for reasons of type erasure, is that *this isn't something that's possible*.

Based on other examples of how to create arrays of generic type parameters it seems like something like the following code should work, but ultimately it fails only at the return of the function where the `Object[][]` cannot be cast to an `Integer[][]`.  It would fail earlier except that IIRC the initial cast of `(T[][])` is basically removed at compile time and acts to prevent a warning, thus it has no real impact.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[][] toTwoDim(T[] array){
    int halflen = array.length / 2;

    T[][] foo = (T[][]) new Object[2][];

    foo[0] = (T[]) new Object[halflen];
    foo[1] = (T[]) new Object[halflen];

    for(int i = 0; i < halflen; i++){
        foo[0][i] = array[i];
        foo[1][i] = array[i+halflen];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(foo[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(foo[1]));

    return foo;
}

public static void main(String[] a){
    Integer[] bar = {1,2,3,4};
    Integer[][] foo = toTwoDim(bar);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(foo[0]));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your explaining, may be I would find another approach to doing the task.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do.

The basic approach is to use [`java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, dimX, dimY)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) to create the array instance.

- If you want the result array's base type to be the same as the base type of the argument, then use reflection to get the base type from `array.getClass()`.
- If you want the result array's base type to be `<T>`, then you will need to add an extra argument to `toTwoDim` whose type is `Class<T>`, and use it to pass the class object for the desired array base type.  (Type erasure means that it is not possible for the `toTwoDim` method to determine the class object for `<T>` at runtime.  Passing the class object as an argument is the standard workaround.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, which doesn't require suppressing any warnings.

```
public static <T> T[][] toTwoDim(Class<T[][]> clazz, T[] array)  
{  
   int halfLength = array.length / 2;  
   T[][] ret = clazz.cast(Array.newInstance(clazz.getComponentType().getComponentType(), 2, halfLength + 1));  
   System.arraycopy(array, 0, ret[0], 0, halfLength);  
   System.arraycopy(array, halfLength, ret[1], 0, array.length - halfLength);  
   return ret;  
}
```